# More compact and/or elegant way to run multiple regex matches

Tags: python, regex

I am currently running about 100 different regex pattern matching calls on the same string and adding the results to a list.

Shortened example:

```
text = "String to Search"
matches = []

AC1 = re.compile(r'(?:TGA[GA])+')
for m in AC1.finditer(text):
    matches.append([m.start(), m.end(), "AC1", m.group()])

polyAT = re.compile(r'[AT]{6,}')
for m in polyAT.finditer(text):
    matches.append([m.start(), m.end(), "polyAT", m.group()])
```

I am wondering if there is a more compact and/or elegant way to match multiple regex patterns. Perhaps a list of regex objects, but I not sure how to implement something like this if it is even an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a list, like

```
mypats = [("AC1", AC1), ("polyAT", polyAT), ... as many as you like]
```

and then just loop over that at top level:

```
for patname, pat in mypats:
    for m in pat.finditer(text):
        matches.append([m.start(), m.end(), patname, m.group()])
```

For extra credit ;-), build the regexp objects that way too:

```
myregexps = [('AC1', r'(?:TGA[GA])+'), # list of (patname, regexp) pairs
             ('polyAT', r'[AT]{6,}'),
             ...
            ]

mypats = [(patname, re.compile(raw)) for patname, raw in myregexps]
```